# How do I get Horizontal Inverted Scrolling in i3wm?

Tags: ubuntu, i3, touchpad, thinkpad

I recently installed i3wm on my Ubuntu 16.04 system, Thinkpad T450s.
Vertical scrolling worked but was not inverted.
Horizontal scrolling did not work.

To fix vertical scrolling I followed the solution listed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/4phohu/help_with_natural_scrolling_on_ubuntu_running_i3/).

To enable horizontal scrolling, [this](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/1052/trackpad-horizontal-scrolling.1.html) solution worked for me.

However, horizontal scrolling was not inverted.
How is this achieved?

Answer (score 2):

The solution for this problem follows the same format as [this one](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/1052/trackpad-horizontal-scrolling.1.html)

These commands showed me that the scrolling distance property had a positive value for the horizontal direction.
`xinput --list`
`xinput --watch-props <id>`

I used the following command to achieve inverted horizontal scrolling:
`xinput --set-prop <id> "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" -113 -113`

Comment: The watch props command returned a long list of libinput entries. As it says here (https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/scrolling.html#natural-scrolling-vs-traditional-scrolling) libinput has a scroll direction toggle. I could activate reversed scrolling by enabling Natural Scrolling: `xinput --set-prop 13 "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the synaptic client, it's a bit more user friendly.

Show all properties

```
synclient
```

Change scroll direction

```
synclient VertScrollDelta=-79
```

Enable horizontal scrolling

```
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1 HorizScrollDelta=-79
```